# Background Images On iOS

Tags: ipad, background-image, master-detail

I'm created a Master Detail app on Xcode 4.x for iPad. I've tried adding a custom background image to the detail part of it which works fine the problem is the background image is appearing pixalated. The image is of size 2048 x 1546 (for the Retina screen on my iPad) and if I view it as a photo on the iPad it doesn't appear pixalated so why does it when it's being used as a background?

The code I'm using to set it is,

UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leather.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;

The only thing I could think of is because a Master Detail app has the scroll bar at the side but how would I fix that? Or what is the real cause? It appears pixalated or any orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an image with the filename "leather@2x.png", otherwise `UIImage` won't recognize that it's supposed to be a high-resolution image. Alternatively, you may want to use a regular `UIImageView` instead of a pattern color.

Comment: Ahh totally forgot that step! I'm not using UIImageView as there is loads of elements to go on top as well as other UIImageViews so it seems easier to manage without too many UIIMAGEVIEW